# Python webscraping script is not working, CSV comes up without data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape information from the "Graphic Novels" category of this website: [[https://www.fishpond.co.nz/Books/Fiction_Literature/Comics_Graphic_Novels/Superheroes?page=1]]

The information I want to extract is:

1. The title of the graphic novel
2. The price
3. The format ( i.e. hardback or paperback).

When I run the script, the CSV is created but without any data from the website. I am not sure what is happening.

I am trying to step-through on a line-by-line basis but cant figure it out.

I have just started learning web-scraping with python and would really appreciate your help with this.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

books = []
for i in range (1,3):
    url = f"https://www.fishpond.co.nz/Books/Fiction_Literature/Comics_Graphic_Novels/Superheroes?page={i}.html"
    response = requests.get(url)
    response = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    div = soup.find('div')
    articles = div.find_all('article',class_ = 'b-list')

    for article in articles:
        title = article.find('a', class_ = 'item-block__title')
        title = title.attrs['title']
        bookformat = article.find('item-block__format')
        price = article.find('span', class_ = 'item-block__price').text
        price = float(price[1:])
        books.append([title,bookformat,price])

df = pd.DataFrame(books,columns=['title','bookformat','price'])
df.to_csv('fishpondscrape.csv')
```

I was expecting the csv to be populated with data along the three attributes of: title,format (bookformat: hardback/paperback), and price. But the output is blank except for the column headers.

Answer (score 0):

Those three infos are hold by a [*JSON*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) script tag (*which makes your task easy*) :

```
import requests
import json
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

root_url = "https://www.fishpond.co.nz/Books/Fiction_Literature/Comics_Graphic_Novels/Superheroes"

books = defaultdict(list)

for i in range(1, 3):
    url = f"{root_url}?page={i}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    articles = json.loads(soup.find("script", {"id": "browse"}).string)
    for article in articles:
        books["title"].append(article["name"])
        for offer in article["offers"]:
            books["format"].append(offer["itemOffered"]["bookFormat"])
            books["price"].append(offer["price"])

df = pd.DataFrame(books)

#df.to_csv("fishpondscrape.csv") # uncomment this line to make a .csv
```

Output :

```
                                            title     format   price
15         One-Punch Man, Vol. 18 (One-Punch Man)  Paperback   16.18
21  Preacher: The 25th Anniversary Omnibus Vol. 2   Hardback  160.00
16         One-Punch Man, Vol. 12 (One-Punch Man)  Paperback   16.39
..                                            ...        ...     ...
13       X-men Vs. Apocalypse: The Twelve Omnibus   Hardback  150.00
10          All Star Superman: The Deluxe Edition   Hardback   54.71
35          One-Punch Man Vol #2 by Yusuke Murata  Paperback   16.98

[47 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Worked like a charm. Just one line is missing from the beginning block:  "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup".

Comment: A quick question: the script runs fine till page 59 of the website i.e range(1,59). But when i try going beyond page 60, i am getting a KeyError: 'bookFormat'. What could be the reason for this? Thanks